# How to split pdf file by result in java pdfbox

Tags: java, pdfbox

**I hve one pdf file, which contain 60 pages. In each pages I've unique and repeated Invoice Nos. Im using Apache PDFBOX.**

```
import java.io.*;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.*;
import org.apache.pdfbox.util.*;
import java.util.regex.*;

public class PDFtest1 {
public static void main(String[] args){
PDDocument pd;
try {

     File input = new File("G:\\Sales.pdf");

     // StringBuilder to store the extracted text
     StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
     pd = PDDocument.load(input);
     PDFTextStripper stripper = new PDFTextStripper();

     // Add text to the StringBuilder from the PDF
     sb.append(stripper.getText(pd));


     Pattern p = Pattern.compile("Invoice No.\\s\\w\\d\\d\\d\\d\\d\\d\\d\\d\\d\\d");

     // Matcher refers to the actual text where the pattern will be found
     Matcher m = p.matcher(sb);

     while (m.find()){
         // group() method refers to the next number that follows the pattern we have specified.
         System.out.println(m.group());
     }

     if (pd != null) {
         pd.close();
     }
   } catch (Exception e){
     e.printStackTrace();
    }
 }
 }
```

**I'm able to read all Invoice Nos. using java regex.
Finally the Result is as follow**

```
run:
Invoice No. D0000003010
Invoice No. D0000003011
Invoice No. D0000003011
Invoice No. D0000003011
Invoice No. D0000003011
Invoice No. D0000003012
Invoice No. D0000003012
Invoice No. D0000003012
Invoice No. D0000003013
Invoice No. D0000003013
Invoice No. D0000003014
Invoice No. D0000003014
Invoice No. D0000003015
Invoice No. D0000003016
```

I need to split the pdf according to tht Invoice No.s. For example Invoice No. D0000003011, all pdf pages should be merge as a single pdf and so on.
Hw can i achive dis. ..

Comment: Are identical invoice numbers always together? What PDFBox version are you using?

Comment: yes, in some pages invoice no are unique and in some pages repeats with same values i.e., duplicate copy. Im using PDFBox 0.7.3. jar file and also using PDFBox-app-1.8.10. jar also....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, COSVisitorException
{
    File input = new File("G:\\Sales.pdf");

    PDDocument outputDocument = null;
    PDDocument inputDocument = PDDocument.loadNonSeq(input, null);
    PDFTextStripper stripper = new PDFTextStripper();
    String currentNo = null;
    for (int page = 1; page <= inputDocument.getNumberOfPages(); ++page)
    {
        stripper.setStartPage(page);
        stripper.setEndPage(page);
        String text = stripper.getText(inputDocument);
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("Invoice No.(\\s\\w\\d\\d\\d\\d\\d\\d\\d\\d\\d\\d)");

        // Matcher refers to the actual text where the pattern will be found
        Matcher m = p.matcher(text);
        String no = null;
        if (m.find())
        {
            no = m.group(1);
        }
        System.out.println("page: " + page + ", value: " + no);

        PDPage pdPage = (PDPage) inputDocument.getDocumentCatalog().getAllPages().get(page - 1);

        if (no != null && !no.equals(currentNo))
        {
            saveCloseCurrent(currentNo, outputDocument);
            // create new document
            outputDocument = new PDDocument();
            currentNo = no;
        }
        if (no == null && currentNo == null)
        {
            System.out.println ("header page ??? " + page + " skipped");
            continue;
        }
        // append page to current document
        outputDocument.importPage(pdPage);
    }
    saveCloseCurrent(currentNo, outputDocument);
    inputDocument.close();
}

private static void saveCloseCurrent(String currentNo, PDDocument outputDocument)
        throws IOException, COSVisitorException
{
    // save to new output file
    if (currentNo != null)
    {
        // save document into file
        File f = new File(currentNo + ".pdf");
        if (f.exists())
        {
            System.err.println("File " + f + " exists?!");
            System.exit(-1);
        }
        outputDocument.save(f);
        outputDocument.close();
    }
}
```

Beware:

- this has not been tested with your file (because I don't have it);
- the code makes the assumption that identical invoice numbers are always together;
- your regular expression has been changed slightly;
- make sure that the first and the last PDF files are correct, and check a few at random, and with different viewers if available;
- verify that the total count of files is as expected;
- the summed up size of all files will be bigger than the source file, this is because of the font resources;
- use the 1.8.10 version. Don't use PDFBox 0.7.3.jar at the same time!
- error handling is very basic, you need to change it;

update 19.8.2015:

- it now supports pages with no invoice number, these will be appended.

Comment: @KiranP to skip the empty page, just replace the "nothing found on page" segment lines with "continue;", i.e. code like this: if (!m.find())
        {
            continue;
        }   Or is the requirement that some pages don't have the invoice#, but do still have to be appended?

Comment: @KiranP code has been improved, hopefully it helps. Please learn to be very exact, i.e. don't write "the second PDF is empty" when you really mean "the second page of the source PDF doesn't have an invoice#".

Comment: @KiranP I see there was a bug, I improved the code again. Please look if it works now.