# How to split a PDF using Apache PDFBox?

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox

I am using Apache PDFBox to handle PDF files in my Java application. I would like to split a PDF document, for example, on every page.

Is it possible to do this wirth Apache PDFBox? If so, how?

Comment: For some advanced splitting, see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32002830/how-to-split-pdf-file-by-result-in-java-pdfbox Btw in the future, consider a google search before asking a one-line question. Searching for "pdfbox split" in google finds just the class from the answer by Tunaki.

Comment: I still need an example.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is possible using a [`Splitter`](http://pdfbox.apache.org/docs/1.8.10/javadocs/org/apache/pdfbox/util/Splitter.html).

This is a sample code that will split a document on every page:

```
PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(myPDF);
Splitter splitter = new Splitter();
List<PDDocument> splittedDocuments = splitter.split(document);
```

You can control the number of pages on every splitted PDF using [`setSplitAtPage(split)`](http://pdfbox.apache.org/docs/1.8.10/javadocs/org/apache/pdfbox/util/Splitter.html#setSplitAtPage%28int%29).

Comment: What does List<PDDocument> do

Comment: I am a java beginner and have never used <> before.

Comment: This is called Generics. You should look at a [tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/index.html) about it.

Comment: @ShaheedulIslam It means a list of PDDocument elements.

Comment: And I am hoping that splitting PDF like this won't cause loss in any internal structure tree (tags to be precise).

Comment: Do you have to close every instance os splittedDocuments or just close document? I'm doing only the latter and see lots of warnings: Warning: You did not close a PDF Document