# PDFBox Split into 3 at specified page numbers (to insert pdf)

Tags: java, pdfbox

I've read the posts [How to split a PDF using Apache PDFBox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32259167/how-to-split-a-pdf-using-apache-pdfbox) and [How to merge two PDF files into one in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3585329/how-to-merge-two-pdf-files-into-one-in-java)  However, it only demonstrates how to split it at every page or into equal chucks and the merger apis for addSource() seem to only have *File*, *String* and *InputStream* and **not** PDDocument.

I would like to insert a one page pdf file into 3 places of a larger pdf file (say 100 pages) at specified pages numbers, e.g. pages 3, 7 and 10.  So, I need to split the larger document at page 3, 7, 10, then insert the one page pdf doc, and then merge all the splits parts together in a new pdf file.

I have attempted to do as follows:

```
        PDDocument doc;
        PDDocument onePage;
        Splitter splitDoc = new Splitter();
        PDFMergerUtility mergedDoc = new PDFMergerUtility();

        onePage = PDDocument.load("/path/onepage.pdf");
        doc = PDDocument.load("/path/hundredpages.pdf");
        splitDoc.setSplitAtPage(1); // inefficient
        // is there a better solution for split?
        List<PDDocument> splitDocs = splitDoc.split(doc);

        for (int i=0; i<splitDocs.size(); i++) {

            if (i==2 || i==7 || i==10) { // only to demonstrate

                mergeFiles.addSource(onePage); // see comment below

            } else {

                // doesn't accept PDDocument 
                // what's the alternative without resorting to InputStream
                mergeFiles.addSource(splitDocs.remove(0)); 

            }


        }

        mergedDoc.setDestinationFileName("/path/mergeddoc.pdf");
        mergedDoc.mergeDocuments();
```

Where are my going wrong or is there a better way?

Comment: Does my answer help or do you still have issues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*This answer is about what you actually want to achieve, i.e.*

> *I would like to insert a one page pdf file into 3 places of a larger pdf file (say 100 pages) at specified pages numbers, e.g. pages 3, 7 and 10.*

*and not what you think you have to do for that, i.e.*

> *So, I need to split the larger document at page 3, 7, 10, then insert the one page pdf doc, and then merge all the splits parts together in a new pdf file.*

*Furthermore, I assume you still are using a PDFBox version 1.8.x, not a 2.0.0 release candidate.*

To insert pages into a document (represented by a `PDDocument` instance) you actually don't have to split and re-merge that document, you merely have to add the page at the given indices. Thus, we can simplify the approach.

At the same time, though, there is a detail in your task which complicates it again: You cannot insert the identical page object multiple times into the same target document, one at least has to create a shallow copy of it.

Taking this into account, you can *insert a one page pdf file into 3 places of a larger pdf*:

```
PDDocument document = ...;
PDDocument singlePageDocument = ...;
PDPage singlePage = (PDPage) singlePageDocument.getDocumentCatalog().getAllPages().get(0);

PDPageNode rootPages = document.getDocumentCatalog().getPages();
rootPages.getKids().add(3-1, singlePage);
singlePage.setParent(rootPages);
singlePage = new PDPage(new COSDictionary(singlePage.getCOSDictionary()));
rootPages.getKids().add(7-1, singlePage);
singlePage = new PDPage(new COSDictionary(singlePage.getCOSDictionary()));
rootPages.getKids().add(10-1, singlePage);
rootPages.updateCount();

document.save(...);
```

*([InsertPages.java](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-pdfbox1/blob/master/src/test/java/mkl/testarea/pdfbox1/merge/InsertPages.java) method `testInsertPages`)*

***Beware,*** though, this code assumes a flat page tree. In case of deeper page trees one has to walk the page list differently: To insert a page as nth document page, you cannot simply add it at position n-1 to the **Pages** root but instead have to inspect its kids one by one, and if coming along an inner `PDPageNode` object, you have to read its `Count` value to check the number of pages it contains; if this number implies that the position to insert at is contained within, you have to recurse into that inner `PDPageNode` object.