# What can i do in PDF by java

Tags: java, pdf-generation

I am a 2nd year university student . in my java course I submit my project PDF spilt and merge . in this project I want to make that if I give page numbers of the PDF then only these pages make another smaller PDF . thus I save memory . but I didn't know PDF is so much complicated . today I am fully afraid knowing about PDF . is it able to do it with java code ?. please help me . and how much thing in PDF Ican do with java . please help me...... thank in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to split a pdf using aapache pdfbox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32259167/how-to-split-a-pdf-using-apache-pdfbox)

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow... be aware that it isn't a forum or a chatroom, and not about opinions or emotions. The site is best to get answers how to do something with code. And yes, your question is a duplicate, see link above, but the answer below is good too. Yes PDF is very complex. That's why there are libraries like PDFBox :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
PDDocument document = PDDocument.load("full path here ...\\pdfFile.pdf");
Splitter splitter = new Splitter();
List<PDDocument> splittedDocuments = splitter.split(document);
```

To control the number of pages on every splitted PDF use : `setSplitAtPage(split)`

Necessary Libraries : [Apache PDFBox](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.pdfbox/pdfbox/1.1.0)  and [Apache Commons Logging](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-logging/commons-logging/1.2)

Take a look at [`setSplitAtPage`](http://pdfbox.apache.org/docs/1.8.10/javadocs/org/apache/pdfbox/util/Splitter.html#setSplitAtPage%28int%29)